# Databinding in the same Control on 2 different DataContext

Tags: silverlight, binding, datacontext

In Silverlight I've a page with some controls and a listbox.

I'm using MVVM and the dataContext of the listbox is defined like this. In my model I have a property ProductCommand and this ProductCommand object contains a list of product named Products.

My listbox is in a grid with the datacontext defined as the ProductCommand property. and the databinding for the listbox is set to the Products (Binding="{Product, Mode=twoWay}").

In my model class I also have a selectedProduct property, and I want to bound it to the SelectedItem property of the listbox.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems I found this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx)  article by Dan Wahlin on a Data Context Proxy very helpful.

Of course in Silverlight 5 ancestor binding will also provide you a means to solve this issue.